# show hide div based on select in small screens

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a select element which I want to appear only on smaller screens, say < 600px.

I want the 2 boxes to both appear on larger screens, but when I get below 600px, I want the select to appear, and then only show `#core-box` and hide `#pro-box`, then according to the select option, will show hide core/pro.

How can I modify my jQuery to do this?

At the moment, I have the select hidden in a CSS media query, and appears at 599px, but on larger screens, only the `#core-box` is showing.

```js
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .blog-filters {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#selectMe").change(function(){
    $( "select option:selected").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="core"){
            $("#pro-box").hide();
            $("#core-box").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="pro"){
            $("#core-box").hide();
            $("#pro-box").show();
        }
    });
  }).change();
  });
```

```html
<div class="blog-filters">
  <div class="select-container">
    <select id="selectMe">
      <option value="core">Core</option>
      <option value="pro">Pro</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pricing-box" id="core-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="core">
        <h2>Core</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pricing-box" id="pro-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="core">
        <h2>Pro</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please quickly add your media query to your question.

Comment: I’ve added that css media query now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by updating your jquery code as following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if(this.value === "core"){
        $("#pro-box").hide();
        $("#core-box").show();
    }
    if(this.value === "pro"){
        $("#core-box").hide();
        $("#pro-box").show();
    }
  });
});
```

and add this code to your CSS

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #pro-box{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

And don't forget to change Pro box `h2` text to be pro so you can see the difference on showing and on hiding, Enjoy!

Comment: This worked great thank you, but i have found a little bug.  So the Show/hide works great. But if i resize my browser above 600px then the dropdown disappears (correctly) but only the selected box shows. the other box is still hidden.